# Change the style of specific programs in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xfce, style

Is it possible to change the style of a specific program while using another style for the entire desktop in Xubuntu 12.04? For example, I would like to use the `Xfce-dusk` style for the entire desktop and most programs, but I would like to use something like `greybird` for qgit, meld, and my text editor. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: See if this answer is helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/47620/25656 but this solution seems limited to gtk2 apps and not to qt or gtk3 apps.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thanks @vasa1! Do you want to post that as the answer so I can select it as correct?

Comment: Why don't you make a detailed answer yourself explaining what you did? No problems for me if you do so :) That would help other Xfce/Xubuntu users as well.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks again, @vasa1.

Comment: Good! After a couple of days (I think), you'll be allowed to accept your own answer if no better one, in your opinion, comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meng Tian already answered this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21148/openoffice-calc-sheet-tabs-and-buttons/47620#47620), but the answer is probably even more relevant to my question. Since I did things slightly differently, I'm posting my own answer here.

You can launch programs with a different style/theme by placing `GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/YourFavoriteTheme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` before your program's command when running the program from the command line.

For example, if you wanted to run `leafpad` with the `Bluebird` style/theme, you could just enter this at the command line:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Bluebird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc leafpad
```

If you want to make this simpler, you can create an executable `.sh` script file and put this code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Bluebird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc leafpad "$@"
```

If you do this, you can also create a launcher for this script which will launch the program in the correct style.

**Note:** the `"$@"` allows you to pass arguments through your script to your program. This was all I needed for my purposes, but if you need to do something fancy like pipe output to the program, this script may not work.